# Simple JSON visualization with angular-google-chart

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I'm trying to make a tree map of a JSON object. I'd just like to be able to expand/contract the levels in the JSON object, and see the value/keys in color on the lowest levels.

I'm trying to do this with angular-google-chart, but keep getting

> Cannot draw chart: no data specified.

Here's my code:

JS

```
var chart1 = {};
chart1.type = "TreeMap";
chart1.data = H2JModel.output
model.chart = chart1;
```

HTML

```
<div google-chart chart="model.chart" style="{{model.chart.cssStyle}}"/>
```

My JSON object is the structure of a database. It looks basically like this:

```
[{ "Table":
  { "Properties" : [
    { "name" : "About"}
  ]},
  { "Columns" : [
     { 
       "name": "Name",
       "unique": "false",
       "type": "String"
     }
   ]}
 }
}]
```

Except it's all in one long string with no breaks. How can I get a simple visualization of this JSON? Is there a better framework to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tree map isn't what you expect. The [Google Charts Tree Map](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap) just shows a rectangular block diagram with divisions and colors based on some value in your data. Clicking on one of the blocks allows you to drill down to the next level of your data's "Tree" structure.

I think you're looking for something more like the [Angular Tree Control](https://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control/).

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to [`angular-google-chart` library](https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart), then it supports [Google Treemap chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap), here is a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/YXO0gYhQf1qwI6WsiRp2?p=preview).

In your case `H2JModel.output` needs to be converted to JSON data *supported* by Treemap chart before the chart is displayed. Here is the example of data format:

```
chart1.data = [
          ['Name', 'Parent Name', 'Value'],
          ['Global',    null,                 0],
          ['America',   'Global',             0],
          ['Europe',    'Global',             0],
          ['Asia',      'Global',             0],
          ['Australia', 'Global',             0],
          ['Africa',    'Global',             0],
          ['Brazil',    'America',            11],
          ['USA',       'America',            52],
          ['Mexico',    'America',            24],
          ['Canada',    'America',            16],
          ['France',    'Europe',             42],
          ['Germany',   'Europe',             31],
          ['Sweden',    'Europe',             22],
          ['Italy',     'Europe',             17],
          ['UK',        'Europe',             21]
        ];
```